# Which Spring Batch Partition is best suited

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have one DB having around 400k records and using spring batch I need to migrate that to another DB.
Using single threaded step may not give me performance edge , so thought of using scalability options provided by spring batch.

After reading from multiple posts and documentation, I got to know below are the ways by which you could optimize the batch job.

1. Multithreaded Step : Not good if you need retry functionality
2. AsyncItemProcessor/AsynItemWriter : unsuitable for my usecase as reader also need to work in parallel
3. Partitioning : Thinking of using local partitioning as remote need inbound/outbound channels.
4. Remote Chunking : Does not want to use it due to extra complexity

Please suggest best approach for my usecase.

I am thinking to use local partitioning. However, as the id column is varchar, I am unable to understand how to partition that and spring batch example shows the example of ColumnRangePartitioner where column is numeric id.

Does gridSize represent number of slave threads which will be spawned? If yes, I want to make it dynamic using Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()+1. is that right approach for I/O Job?

Comment: According to your description, option 1 is not good, option 2 is unsuitable and you do not want to use option 4. So you are left with option 3 :-). I will add an answer.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine As i have limited knowledge, so please suggest if my analogy is fine for rejecting option 1,2,4 ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does gridSize represent number of slave threads which will be spawned?

Not necessarily. The grid size is the number of partitions that will be created by the partitioner. Note that this is just a hint to the partitioner, some partitioners do not use it (like the `MultiResourcePartitioner`).

This is different from the number of workers. You can have more partitions than workers and vice versa.

> If yes, I want to make it dynamic using Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()+1.

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` to dynamically spawn as much workers as available cores (even though I don't see the value of adding 1 to that, unless I'm missing something).

> is that right approach for I/O Job?

It depends on how you are processing each record. But I think this is a good start since each worker will handle a different partition and all workers can be executed in parallel.

Comment: As the id column is varchar both in my source and target DB, I am unable to understand how to partition that ?

Comment: The id column is unique. Only issue is that it's of varchar type and not numeric. I tried to use ColumnRangePartitioner example but there id column is numeric, so max and min got calculated. Mine is varchar, so I am clueless what logic should I use.

Comment: As i have limited knowledge, so please suggest if my analogy is fine for rejecting option 1,2,4 ?